# Why is WordPress Answers so unfriendly as compared to StackOverflow etc.?

Tags: discussion

I've only asked three questions here on WordPress Answers. I won't be asking any more. In fairness to the WordPress Answers Community, I'm stating why. In Area 51, StackOverflow, etc., I've gotten courteous and useful responses to all questions. Not here! Strange indeed.

Comment: Could you please add examples? I haven't seen anything offensive in the responses to your questions.

Answer (score 9):

> In Area 51, StackOverflow, etc., I've gotten courteous and useful
>   responses to all questions. Not here! Strange indeed.

Your first [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81591/making-epub-pdf-mobi-formats-available-in-a-post) was an exact duplicate.

The other 2 questions are kind of vague and a little too wordy in my opinion. They are the kind of questions I wouldn't even attempt to answer because I don't really understand what your asking.

I don't think anyone has been discourteous and if you want more useful answers try asking better focused questions.  Present a specific problem along with your attempt to solve it. Sometimes you have to try something and fail before you can ask a good question. You need to have a better understanding of what you are asking.

Just my .02

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind we're not a service, you dont complain to the manager and get 20% off, we're real people, doing it in our own time, for free, it's a two way street and we have to put up with a lot of self righteous people and abuse.

However, I don't see any issues with the responses to your questions

Wyck here didn't understand exactly what you were asking here:

[Members area with externally-managed htaccess / htpasswd authentication?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81589/members-area-with-externally-managed-htaccess-htpasswd-authentication)

Kaiser said something similar, and your other question was a duplicate.

There's nothing wrong with stating a question is unclear, it's a strong hint that you can edit to clarify, or perhaps that Wyck had a potential answer but was unsure? Only Wyck/Kaiser knows, but one can always improve a question, and if you took it as an insult, you shouldn't, none was intended.

We're approachable, and while sometimes we may be blunt, the majority of us aren't rude, and those that are rude tend not to stay for very long. We have the chat for more offtopic issues ( e.g. plugin recommendations ), and there're plenty of resources on improving a question so it's easier to answer.

Which is the problem you had, your questions, although they made sense to you, they didn't to others. Some people guessed and figured it out, but if you had gone back and edited and reformatted the question you would have gotten better answers.

*The difference between WordPress Answers and other sites is we took the time to tell you and you didn't like it.*